# How to replace last part of URL using Regex and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm not using REGEX very often so I don't know it well.
Want to match last digits before `/` end of string.
so my regex will be`\d+/$`
Now I want to replace matched part of href inside the  link.
First thing

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
var regex = \d+/$
```

so I escaped it (I think) `var regex = /\d+//$`

I thought it will be simple from now:

```
$('a').attr('href').replace(regex,'00/')
```

But it seems no use.

I'm using firebug console for testing

Comment: An example each for original url and replaced url will help.

Comment: To escape the slash, you want `/\d+\/$/`

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is this :

```
$('a').attr('href', function(_,h){ return h.replace(/\d+\/$/,'00/') });
```

A slash is escaped as `\/` in a regex literal, not as `//`.

`$(selector).attr(name, fun)` will apply the function to each element.

Comment: `TypeError: h.replace is not a function` copy pasta so im sure i get it right

Comment: @Lord_JABA Sorry, forgot a thing

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
url = "www.example.com/event/detail/46/"
var value = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
url = url.replace(value, '00')
```

Comment: I seen this method and it will probably work but I wan't to learn how to do this with regex because it will not always be that simple

Comment: You just check this link. May this will provide your solution. http://blog.adrianlawley.com/jquery-change-url-parameter-value/

Answer (score 0):

In escaping use `\` not `/`.

So this will be

```
var regex = /\d+\$/
```

Comment: result `"www.example.com/event/detail/46/"` -nothing is replaced

Comment: @Lord_JABA When I said it will replace anything, I just pointed out, how to escape characters.